# Error when using `mysqli::escape_string`

Tags: php, mysql, methods, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

Im just using `mysqli::escape_string` to prevent errors from " ` "'s and this error appears:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

**----------------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------**

I did:

```
$DB = new mysqli();
$Escape = $DB->escape_string($String);
```

(I use it a few times)

And I get this:

[image]

Comment: How you used it? post that part of your code

Comment: Will you read the manual page at last?

Answer (score 0):

before call it please create  mysqli object

```
//creating
$myDb  = new mysqli();

//using
$myDb->escape_string($escape_string);
```

Comment: does `$myDb` has to be the connection variable? @Tufan Barış Yıldırım

Answer (score 0):

Basically saying:

This method does not support the call `mysqli::escape_string`

You will need to use the following method :

```
$DB = new mysqli();
$Escape = $DB->escape_string($String);
```

Answer (score 0):

*mysqli::escape_string()* is a static call to the function escape_string(), something which mysqli doesn't support. You should use one of the options above.